# problem with header for making zip not able to download and create

Tags: php, header, zip

Problem with making zip file not able to create and download show only zip name in response

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    $mimeType = 'application/json';
    header("Content-type: " . $mimeType);

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$filename}\""); 

    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . mb_strlen($filename));
    echo $filename;

    flush();
    readfile($filename);
    // delete file
    unlink($filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Content-type like this: `header("Content-type: application/zip");`

Comment: I have try this but same issue getting.

Comment: I also see, that you use mb_strlen to define the Content-Length. I think you must define there the content size of the zip file like this:
"Content-length: " . filesize($filename)
But i don't know if this causes the issue.

Comment: after use content-length show following error ZipArchive::close(): Read error: Bad file descriptor in

Comment: That sounds like the zip file could not be opened. Can you show the content of $filename? Is the $filename correct and does the file exist?

Comment: zip is created and download by hitting static URL but not created and download dynamically.

Comment: when you do echo $filename, what does exactly appear?

Comment: print file name i.e; invoice.zip

Comment: So maybe you need the full path of the file instead of only the filename.